# Cannot mutate (set) .isHidden on a banner ad

Tags: ios, iad

I have an iAd banner in my storyboard and dragged an outlet to my class.  I'm just trying to do a simple implementation right now (no animation) but don't see why "No setter method 'setIsHidden' for assignment to property" is being thrown as an error when I try to set self.adBanner.isHidden?  I've included the iAd framework.

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface MyClass () <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adBanner;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize adBanner = _adBanner;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.adBanner.delegate = self;
  self.adBanner.isHidden = YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  self.adBanner.isHidden = NO;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
  self.adBanner.isHidden = YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Rolled back to original version to preserve the context of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to "mutate" (set) a getter there.  Use `self.adBanner.hidden = YES` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, silly mistake.  `isHidden` is a read-only property.  I was mistaking that property for `hidden`.  Here is final working code for reference:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface MyClass () <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adBanner;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize adBanner = _adBanner;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.adBanner.delegate = self;
  self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  self.adBanner.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
  self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant this to be a comment?